# Docker Volume Not Syncing

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The following volume is not syncing...
[image]

When I put something in the Graph folder in the docker container, the graph folder on the local disk remains empty.

**YAML file:**

```
# Compose file format version
version: "3.7"

# Contains services where each service contains configurations that will be applied to each container started for that service.
services:
     my_web_service:
          # Where the Dockerfile is
          build: .
          working_dir: /my_project
          volumes:
               - type: volume
                 source: ./Graph
                 target: /my_project/Graph
          # Interactive Console
          stdin_open: True   # Same as docker run -i
          tty: True          # Same as docker run -t

# Declare named volumes and their optional parameters.
volumes:
     Graph:
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python

# Output to terminal in real-time
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Enable path conversion from Windows-style to Unix-style in volume definitions
ENV COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1

RUN mkdir /my_project

WORKDIR /my_project

COPY . /my_project

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I think you have to mount it through the Docker Desktop UI. Go to Settings->Resources->File Sharing. Put the full path to the directory in there. Unless you are using WSL2. Then, take a look at this: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#volume-mounting-requires-shared-folders-for-linux-containers.

Comment: try change the volume to  `volumes: \n - ./Graph:/my_project/Graph `

Comment: @frank_lee I get the error: `ERROR: In file '.\docker-compose.yml', volume must be a mapping, not an array.`

Comment: do you break the line between `volumes:` and `- ./Graph:/my_project/Graph`  ?